# How to add links of websites with their logo/icon in LaTeX?

Tags: templates, cv

```
- \profilepic{alice.jpeg}
- \cvname{Alice}
- \cvjobtitle{Advanture}
- \cvdate{26 November, 1865}
- \cvaddress{United Kingdom}
- \cvnumberphone{+880567632189}
- \cvsite{http://en.wikipedia.org}
- \cvmail{alice@gmail.com}
```

This code has been taken from Overleaf that works based on online. I would like to add two more lines in this code. Below the line showing phone number, I want to delete cv site, and want to add my Facebook and LinkedIn profiles links. And I want to show these two links in such a way that only my name will be shown in blue color and when anyone will click on my name, they will automatically visit my profiles. I also want at the left hand side of these links, their logo/icon (Facebook logo and LinkedIn logo) will be shown.

Please instruct me how I can do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is very far from general LaTeX code, which packages are being used?  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), without an MWE this question is unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: You should have mentioned that it is about the [Twenty Seconds Curriculum Vitae in LaTex](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae-in-latex/xknxnmscghyt) (sic!) template.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get what I want? I know little about LaTeX. But I thought Overleaf is related to LaTeX, and all codes of Overleaf can be used in LaTeX. It would be wrong if I ask someone to write a code for me so that I can get what I want and that code will support in Overleaf, but I am helpless at this moment since I don't know anything about LaTeX. I request to the experts of this forum to help so that I can get rid from this problem.

Comment: Overleaf is a LaTeX compiler, so code from Overleaf is indeed LaTeX code, the point I meant to make was that by default commands like `\cvname` aren't defined.  The document you copied them from either has some lines which defines them or loads a class/package which defines them.  This is why a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is necessary.  In this case it seems the information I was after was that this used the `twentysecondcv` class.  Linking to the template would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I have understood what I should have done. It would be helpful if I would have mentioned that it is about Twenty Seconds Curriculum Vitae. But I can not realize it at the beginning. Please, pardon me for my mistake. Since you have already known about Twenty Seconds Curriculum Vitae, would it possible for you to provide what I want? If you have enough time, please do something for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the following to the preamble (between `\documentclass{twentysecondcv}` and `\begin{document}`)

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\givenfacebook}{}
\newcommand{\givenlinkedin}{}

\newcommand{\cvfacebook}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenfacebook}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvlinkedin}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenlinkedin}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\makeprofile}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9.90cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{13pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);

        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\givenprofilepic}};
\end{tikzpicture}

{\Huge\color{mainblue}\givencvname}

\begin{flushright}
{\Large\color{black!80}\givencvjobtitle}
\end{flushright}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \givennumberphone\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \givencvsite}\\
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenfacebook}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faFacebook}} & \href{http://www.facebook.com/\givenfacebook }{\givencvname}\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenlinkedin}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faLinkedin}} & \href{http://www.linkedin.com/in/\givenlinkedin }{\givencvname}\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail}{\givencvmail}}
\end{tabular}


\profilesection{About me}{3.2cm}
\givenaboutme


\profilesection{Skill}{5cm}
\givenskill
\giventextskill
\noindent
\scriptsize
\noindent
(*)[The skill scale is from 0 (Fundamental Awareness) to 6 (Expert).]

\end{flushleft}
\end{textblock}
\vspace{-10pt}
}
```

The [`fontawesome`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package is used for the facebook and linkedin logos.  The original code for `\makeprofile` from `twentysecondcv.cls` is sourced from https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex/

Two new commands `\cvfacebook{foo}` and `\cvlinkedin{bar}` are defined to make the facebook link point to `www.facebook.com/foo` and the linkedin link point to `www.linkedin.com/in/bar`.

The only changes within `\renewcommand{\makeprofile}` are that I added the two lines

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenfacebook}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faFacebook}} & \href{http://www.facebook.com/\givenfacebook }{\givencvname}\\}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenlinkedin}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faLinkedin}} & \href{http://www.linkedin.com/in/\givenlinkedin }{\givencvname}\\}
```

The personal details on the left are then specified by

```
\profilepic{alice.jpeg} %path of profile pic
\cvname{Alice} %your name
\cvjobtitle{Adventurer}%your actual job position
\cvdate{26 November 1865}%date of birth
\cvaddress{United Kingdom}%address
\cvnumberphone{+39 0325658974}%telphone number
\cvmail{alice@wonderland.com}%e-mail
\cvsite{http://en.wikipedia.org}%personal site
\cvfacebook{foo}
\cvlinkedin{bar}
```

These commands should be included in the body of the document.  To remove any of these, just remove (or comment out using `%` at the beginning of the line) the appropriate command.

[image: Image of CV]

Comment: I think, the code I stated at the beginning of code needs to be deleted during compiling,  and all the code you have written I will paste at that place. Am I right?

Comment: One more question. Please tell me where I will write my name, cv date etc in your code.

Comment: You may consider this line. ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}. In this line where will I put the date?

Comment: @user64814 you should copy all of the large code block in my answer and paste it just under `\documentclass{twentysecondcv}`. Use `\cvdate{26 November 1865}` and the others as usual for the rest of the details.  I tried to make a `\cvfacebook` command but that threw an error which I couldn't immediately debug and as the solution is a bit ugly I posted what would work, so for the moment you'll have to update `\newcommand{\givenfacebook}{foo}`.  I'll have another go at getting a `\cvfacebook` macro working and ping you if I can improve on the answer.

Comment: @user64814 I may have been doing something stupid yesterday, things now seem to work. You should copy in the block of code beginning `\usepackage{fontawesome}` (which I've updated since my original answer) and then forget about it entirely.  Below the `\cvdate{26 November 1865}}` commands you can add in `\cvfacebook{foo}` and `\cvlinkedin{bar}` which work in a similar manner to the others, as described in my answer.

Comment: If I understand perfectly, in your last comment, you have said that I needn't copy and paste all of your code. If I just use \cvfacebook{foo} and \cvlinkedin{bar} below \cvdate{26 November 1865}, it would be enough for what I want. Am I right? If I'm right, one more question arises automatically. If I paste the link of Facebook ID in the place of {foo} and replace "foo" with my ID link, will my CV automatically show only the name of my Facebook ID?

Comment: Wait....wait...one more thing...Besides using \cvfacebook{foo} and \cvlinkedin{bar}, I should use \usepackage{fontawesome} at the beginning. Am I right? If I should use \usepackage{fontawesome} at the beginning, please tell me below which line I should place \usepackage{fontawesome}. And if Use \usepackage{fontawesome}, placing link of Facebook ID in the place of {foo}, in real CV my Facebook ID will be shown by the Name of my Facebook ID? Is my statement correct? If it is not, please say what correct is.

Comment: I understood the request being to be that `\cvfacebook{foo}` would link to `www.facebook.com/foo` but to display the argument passed to `\cvname`, I can show how to have it display `foo` and link to `www.facebook.com/foo` instead if that is your preference?  The `fontawesome` package is necessary for the facebook/linkedin symbols so `\usepackage{fontawesome}` must be included in the preamble.

Comment: I can't understand where I will paste the link of my Facebook profile. The link you have already provided is very useful since it contains the section for which Facebook logo and name can be shown easily. But even up to this moment I don't know where I should paste the link of my Facebook profile. I always become scared because I don't know when you will loose your patience. We are already very near to the solution of our problem. And at this moment if I came to know that where I will paste the link of Facebook profile, may be it will be enough for me.

Comment: @user64814 I'm not sure I understand your problem (I appreciate that these things can be difficult to express esp. for new users).  Maybe I have been confusing with my use of foo and bar.  Let us suppose that you have set your name with `\cvname{John Smith}` and that your facebook account is located at `www.facebook.com/user64814` if this is the case then by adding the command `\cvfacebook{user64814}` the text shown next to the fb logo will be `John Smith` which will link to `www.facebook.com/user64814`.  If the text or link should be different, please clarify how you would like it.

Comment: You are near to what I asked. In \cvfacebook{foo}, just "foo" will be replaced with user64814 as you have shown. Am I right? And from your last comment, it seems to me that whole link of Facebook ID needs not to be placed at the place of "foo".

Comment: Indeed, `\cvfacebook{user64814}` or `\cvfacebook{blah}` make the link points to `www.facebook.com/user64814` or `www.facebook.com/blah` respectively.  If the facebook link is `www.facebook.com/person3` and you wish the text displayed in the cv to be `person3` even if the CV name is `John Smith` then swap `\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenfacebook}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faFacebook}} & \href{http://www.facebook.com/\givenfacebook }{\givencvname}\\}` with `\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenfacebook}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\faFacebook}} & \href{http://www.facebook.com/\givenfacebook }{\givenfacebook}\\}`.

Comment: I can't understand why you are writing \href{http://www.facebook.com/. Only mentioning www.faceboo.com can't indicate to a specific ID.  I think we should write \href{http://www.facebook.com/person3 to indicate a particular ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46483/discussion-between-dai-bowen-and-user64814).

Comment: @DaiBowen linkrot...