# How do I add a stackoverflow icon to twentysecondcv?

Tags: cv

I want to add a link to stackoverflow on twentysecondcv. How do I do it?

The section where items are added is currently:

```
\cvlinkedin{/in/xxxxx}
\cvgithub{xxxx}
\cvnumberphone{(0176) 1234567} % Phone number
\cvsite{} % Personal website
\cvmail{person@gmail.com} % Email address
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far (without personal data!).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332967/how-to-add-links-of-websites-with-their-logo-icon-in-latex/332987

Comment: @Christian: Does the link solved your problem?